# Visual Studio MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I want to create a MFC project in Visual Studio where, on button action to go through various functions(like 'prime'). I don't know where to write these function and also the global variables i need for them(p and flag). I have searched on the internet and tried more methods(like declaring them in .h files and so on, but didn't worked). Take in my mind that i very new to this. Here is my code:

```
long int p,flag;
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedClickMe()
{   
    flag = prime(p);
    //more code
}
int prime(long int pr)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Have you used the Class Wizard in Visual Studio?

Comment: If it's only a few functions and variables, make them private members of `CMFCApplication1Dlg`. If it's anything larger consider moving the functionality in a class of it's own and make that class a member of `CMFCApplication1Dlg`. Also note that if function `prime` does anything time-consuming it will block the main thread and you will get a 'window is not responding' while `prime` is executing, to solve that run it in a worker thread.

Comment: You need to try harder to explain your problem.